# How to extract data between brackets in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
 productRankingOct12: [
"LessPopularityEPC"
"CtrEpcJob"
"DeviceSpecificLPE"
 ]
```

I have data in the format specified above. I would like to extract data between the square brackets & store it into array. I have used this code but it seems like it is not working

```
            File.open(input_file, "r") do |f| #f=file descriptor
                f.each_line do |line| 
                puts line.scan(/[([^<>]*)]/)
                end
            end
```

Comment: Is that the exact format? There aren't commas between those strings?

Comment: Why not change the file? You are not too far away from YAML.

Comment: Hiii I have removed the comma from the data as I don't need those

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create a file with the content in your example:

```
text = <<BITTER_END
 productRankingOct12: [
"LessPopularityEPC"
"CtrEpcJob"
"DeviceSpecificLPE"
 ]
BITTER_END

FName = "text"
IO.write(FName, text)
  #=> 79
```

Now simply read the lines of the file and append those that do not contain, say, a left or right bracket, to an initially-empty array:

```
arr = IO.foreach(FName).with_object([]) { |line, a|
 a << line unless line =~ /[\[\]]/ }
  #=> ["\"LessPopularityEPC\"\n",
  #    "\"CtrEpcJob\"\n",
  #    "\"DeviceSpecificLPE\"\n"] 

puts arr
  # "LessPopularityEPC"
  # "CtrEpcJob"
  # "DeviceSpecificLPE"
```

Comment: Hi... thanks for your answer. It works for me.. Could you please tell me if I want to put all the values on the same index then what should I do? 

Also, I want to map this value to productRanking12..

Comment: Chints, sorry, but I don't know what you mean by "...put all the values on the same index [what index?].." or "...map this [what is "this"?] value to productRanking12 [what kind of object is productRanking12, an array, a hash? ]...". If you can clarify I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You regex doesn't seem to be right. Try using an online tool like https://regex101.com/ to check your regex.

I think this regex might suit your needs

```
\"([^";]*)\"
```

If you look at the example at https://regex101.com/r/qR4cQ3/1 it has an explanation which I have put below:

- \" matches the character " literally
- In the 1st Capturing group ([^";]*)

  - [^";]* Match a character that is not a talking mark between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- \" matches the character " literally

In other words, match any text that is not a talking mark but is in between talking marks.

You should also probably read all the text into into one string and then run scan on that so that you get an array of everything, not just for each line.